# How to get the class context of the ativity that initaited intent

Tags: android

I used an intent to call another activity. After that, I collected some data from user using the second activity. I need to update some data in the first activity and close the second activity.

Hence, I need the `Context` (this) of the first activity. How do I do that? Or do I need to start the first activity again as new activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `startActivityForResult()` and **don't finish()** the first activity. You will land to that activity on method `onActivityResult().`

Edit:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
```

and

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       // When you are back from second Activity you are land here ..
       // do what ever you want to, without re Creating the this Activity 
    }
}
```